# Time format conversion with PHP

Tags: php, time

If have the duration for a recipe in the format 1H10M (1 hour, 10 minutes) or 20M (20 minutes). I want to use the format as described in the parentheses. I've tried using `strtotime()` without luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$duration="1H10M5S";
$display=str_replace(array('H','M','S'),
         array(' Hour(s) ',' Minute(s) ',' Seconds'),
         $duration);
echo $display;
```

**Output**

```
1 Hour(s) 10 Minute(s) 5 Seconds
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/385255)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$yourtext = '1H10M';
$newFormat = str_replace("H", " hour,", $yourtext);
$newFormat = str_replace("M", " minutes,", $newFormat);
echo $newFormat;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date_work = new DateTime($variable_name); $inte = $date_work->format('h:i:s');echo $inte;
```

Comment: Hi Karthick,
If $variable_name = "20M", PHP throws an error, as it's unable to parse the 'M'.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function getBetween($content, $start, $end) {
    $r = explode($start, $content);
    if (isset($r[1])) {
        $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
        return $r[0];
        }
    return '';
}

$dur = "1H2M3S";

$hr = strtok($dur, "H");
$min = getBetween($dur, "H", "M");
$sec = getBetween($dur, "M", "S");
```

Do what ever you want to do with $hr, $min and $sec.

Comment: Hi Sherez
My issue is, that I only have "H" sometimes. So sometimes the text will be 20M, and thus only have minutes, and sometimes it will have H as well. Will this still work?

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work for cases other than 1H2M3S. We will have to perform some more checks to handle this.